# Biblatex consequent bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex, and used the following to include it:

```
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib}
```

and at the end:

```
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

And I'm struggling with the format of the `.bib`-file. The problem is, that I have three kinds of "authors":

1. John Doe
2. John Doe, Jonny Doey, Elvis Presley
3. Apache Corporation

Regarding the third one, I found `{{Apache Corporation}}` as author to be what I need. The first and the second are more interesting. What I need is a consequent way to display the names.

Currently for the first, in my bibliograph, I find surname, firstname, so `Doe, John`, in `.bib`-file its `"John Doe"`, for multiple names, its the same syntax in `.bib`-file, but in the bibliography it's showing as firstname, lastname and the same for the other names, instead of last name, first name, when citing, its showing only the first one mentioned (so in my case only John Doe), whereas with only one author, its showing only the surname when citing.

I hope you understand what I mean. To be sure about that, an example.

```
1. @BOOK{....., AUTHOR="John Doe",....}
2. @BOOK{....., AUTHOR="John Doe, Jonny Doey, Elvis Presley",....}
```

First one will show as `Doe, John` in bib and as `Doe` when citing. Second one will show as `John Doe, Jonny Doey, Elvis Presley` in bib (notice now its firstname, surname and not the other way) and as `John Doe` when citing (notice is the full name and not only the surname).

What can i do to have this consequently, so no matter how many authors, its in bib always surname, firstname and when citing always only the surname?

Comment: For multiple authors, write `Lastname, Firstname and Lastname2, Firstname 2 and ...`. Separate authors with `and`. (You can also write `Firstname Lastname and Firstname2 Lastname 2`.)

Comment: Use the keyword and to separate the authors.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I tried the "and", and now I get the first name correctly and the second one as firstname surname... What do I need around the text? `{}`, `{{}}` or `""`?

Comment: also, in text citation now, there are two author names, but is it possible to show only one of the authors there?

Comment: Regarding `last, first, first last` in bibliography, that's normal I think, but might depend on the style. In most cases, either `{}` or `""`, I'm not sure which is recommended. You only want extra braces in cases like the one you've identified (company name which shouldn't be interpreted as firstname lastname), or in titles where you need to make sure capitalization is preserved. For your last question, try adding `maxcitenames=1` to the `biblatex` options.